# Magento 2 Admin Grid Add/Update Button

Tags: admin, grid, magento-2.2.5, custom-button

In Magento 2.2.5, I am creating admin grid by following [this tutorial](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html)(Using layout Block method. **Not UI Component**).

In that I have a add button. I can't remove it. I need to remove it and add a new button with custom url. How to achieve this.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 6):

You can use **update**

```
parent::_construct();
$this->buttonList->update('save', 'onclick', 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getUrl('*/*/<youraction>') . '\')');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this code

```
    parent::_construct();
    $this->removeButton('add');

    $this->buttonList->add(
            '<your name>',
            [
        'label' => __('<your label>'),
        'class' => 'save',
        'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getUrl('*/*/<youraction>') . '\')',
        'style' => '    background-color: #ba4000; border-color: #b84002; box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #007bdb;color: #fff;text-decoration: none;'
            ]
    );
```

Hope that will help you.

Comment: Yes, It is working. I have tried this but before `parent::_construct();` i added this remove button code. So It is not worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this code

```
     protected function _construct()
        {
            $this->_objectId = 'row_id';
            $this->_blockGroup = '[Vendor_name]_[module_name]';
            $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_[Controller_name]';
            parent::_construct();

// for remove btn

            $this->buttonList->remove('save');
            $this->buttonList->remove('back');
            $this->buttonList->remove('reset');
            
/////  for update btn name

            $this->buttonList->update('save', 'label', __('[Updateed_btn_name]'));

/// for add new custome btn
    
            $this->addButton(
                        '<custome_btn_name>',
                        [
                            'label' => __('Btn_name_to_show'),
                            'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $this->getUrl('[Route_name]/[controller_name]/[file_name]')),
                            'class' => 'primary',
                            'level' => 1
                        ]
                    );
        }
```

**[Update]**

> **Another way to add button into Ui-Component**

> **Step-1:** Create Generic.php at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Button

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context;
use Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface;

class Generic
{
    protected $context;
    protected $pageRepository;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageRepositoryInterface $pageRepository
    ) {
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->pageRepository = $pageRepository;
    }

    public function getUrl($route = '', $params = [])
    {
        return $this->context->getUrlBuilder()->getUrl($route, $params);
    }
}
```

> **Step-2:** Create Back.php at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Button

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

class Back extends Generic implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Back'),
            'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $this->getBackUrl()),
            'class' => 'back',
            'sort_order' => 10,
        ];
    }

    public function getBackUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/');
    }
}
```

> **Step-3:** Create Reset.php at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Button

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

class Reset implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Reset'),
            'class' => 'reset',
            'on_click' => 'location.reload();',
            'sort_order' => 30,
        ];
    }
}
```

> **Step-4:** Create Delete.php at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Buttons

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

class Delete extends Generic implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    protected $context;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context
    ) {
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    public function getButtonData()
    {
        $data = [];
        $id = $this->context->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        if ($id) {
            $data = [
                'label' => __('Delete'),
                'class' => 'delete',
                'on_click' => 'deleteConfirm(\'' . __(
                    'Are you sure you want to delete this?'
                ) . '\', \'' . $this->getDeleteUrl() . '\')',
                'sort_order' => 20,
            ];
        }
        return $data;
    }

    public function getDeleteUrl()
    {
        $id = $this->context->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/delete', ['id' => $id]);
    }
}
```

> **Step-5:** Create Save.php at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Button

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Control\Container;

class Save extends Generic implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Save'),
            'class' => 'save primary',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => [
                    'buttonAdapter' => [
                        'actions' => [
                            [
                                'targetName' => 'your_form_ui_component_name.your_form_ui_component_name',
                                'actionName' => 'save',
                                'params' => [
                                    false,
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

> **Step-6:** In your Form Ui-Component file at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component add below code:

```
................................................................................................................
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    ............................................................................................................
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="back" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\Back</item>
        <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\Delete</item>
        <item name="reset" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\Reset</item>
        <item name="save" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\Save</item>
    </item>
    ............................................................................................................
</argument>
................................................................................................................
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Answer (score 1):

use this if you are using ui component

```
   <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="complete" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">View Complete Orders</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">afrax/create/complete</item>
        </item>
         <item name="pending" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="processing" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">View Pending Orders</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">afrax/create/index</item>
        </item>
        <item name="cancel" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="processing" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">View Cancel Orders</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">afrax/create/canceled</item>
        </item>
    </item>
```